# multiple SUM from multiple tables to one query

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have 2 tables: `incomes` & `outgo` both containing information about transactions. I'd like to run a report to show the overall flow of money based on the totals in the tables, I currently do this manually by using the following queries:

```
1) SELECT amount, SUM(amount) AS intotal FROM incomes
2) SELECT amount, SUM(amount) AS outtotal FROM outgo
```

as an example, lets say `intotal` is `500` and `outtotal` is `300`

I'd like a single query that gets both summaries and subtracts the `outtotal` amount from the `intotal` amount with a result of `200` in this case. can anyone point me in the right direction or help me with syntax?

Comment: `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM (SELECT amount FROM incomes UNION SELECT amount FROM outgo) x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try

```
SELECT
    (SELECT amount, SUM(amount) AS intotal FROM incomes) AS a,
    (SELECT amount, SUM(id) AS outtotal FROM outgo) AS b
```

And use with `a.intotal` and `b.outtotal`

### Or directly with

```
SELECT 
    ((SELECT SUM(amount)FROM incomes) - (SELECT SUM(amount)FROM outgo)) AS total
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT
   (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM incomes)
   -
   (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM outgo)
```